# Display Android 'Up Button' with small arrow and logo

Tags: android

I tried the following code from the Android documentation, to display the 'up button':

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ... }
```

According to the documentation the 'up botton' should look like [this](http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-up.png).

However, on my phone with Android 4.2 it looks more like [this](https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRDfAgXlzOwmVufH1z5dsZCW4GyMGdu3pF7yEEZnYzwVx79Olwd).

The arrow is separated from the logo and takes too much place. How can I get the small arrow in combination with the logo?

Comment: This is the old Holo theme your seeing in the documentation, the new UI spec is called Material Design here refer to https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html

Comment: The one you want is the OLD one. The one you're getting is the latest thing. Better make your app look new than old, right?

Comment: In Material Design, showing logo and title at the same time is discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

you can use toolbar  and use setNavigationIcon() method to change the navigation icon

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.SomeIcon);
```